# What does this permission rule mean

Tags: permissions, vps

what does this permission rule means, and is it safe to use it for my VPS server?

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different commands,

1. `sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www` changes the ownership of the `/var/www` folder to user=$USER and group=www-data.
2. `find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;` searches for files under `/var/www` and changes their permissions to 0660, which is equivalent to rw-rw----.
3. `sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;` sets SetGID on the /var/www folder. This is to make sure scripts are always run with group permissions.

There you have it, hope it helps.

Comment: How safe are this.

Comment: It shouldn't break anything, if that is what you mean by safe. It grants the $USER and www-data group read/write access, which is reasonable convenience. Do you have any particular safety concerns?

Comment: Thank you very much.. No particular concern, just want to be sure before i bash something. I can't upvote because of my rep.